Interaction between global stores and `bar.sync`
Suppose I have some PTX that looks like this:
st.global.v4.b32 ...
bar.sync

I know that bar.sync will block execution until the st.global.v4.b32 is visible to all threads in the block. My question is: how long does it take until global stores are visible?
In general, global memory stores are "fire and forget": after store instructions hit the store buffer, threads can continue executing while the store buffer asynchronously commits data to global memory.
At what point in the global memory store operation does bar.sync allow threads to continue execution? Is it:

Once data hits the store buffer?
Once data hits L1 cache?
Once data hits L2 cache?
Once data hits DRAM?

In other words, what is the latency of a global memory store followed by bar.sync?
Edit: I am asking in the context of A100 and H100 specifically.

“I know that bar.sync will block execution until the st.global.v4.b32 is visible to all threads “ — how do you know that? Because I don’t believe it is correct. bar.sync is not a memory fence, it is a simple synchronisation instruction

@talonmies OP seems to be alluding to "The barrier{.cta}.sync or barrier{.cta}.red or barrier{.cta}.arrive instruction guarantees that when the barrier completes, prior memory accesses requested by this thread are performed relative to all threads participating in the barrier.". OP's "all threads" certainly sounds misleading, I guess it should read "all threads participating in the barrier".

bar.sync is a memory fence. See paleonix's comment, also the next paragraph in PTX docs:
"A memory write (e.g., by st, red or atom) has been performed when the value written has become visible to other threads participating in the barrier, that is, when the previous value can no longer be read."

No. bar.sync is __syncthreads(). It is a simple block level instruction barrier.  You tell it how many threads need to arrive at the barrier for it to open (originally only all of the warp, but in more recent evolution of PTX it can be a subset). Every thread decrements an internal state counter, when it reaches 0 it opens. It is not a memory fence.

Thank you @talonmies... in that case could you help me understand what the PTX docs are talking about in regard to memory? I'm new to CUDA :)
My reading of the documentation is that any load after bar.sync is guaranteed to see the value stored before bar.sync

membar.cta is the equivalent block level memory fence (i.e. it's __threadfence_block())

barrier and bar are different things. I think you are confusing the two. bar.sync, as used in the code in the question, only guarantees that every thread reaching the barrier has executed the instructions in its prior code path, which would be firing the write in this case. That is why conditionally executed bar.sync is a deadlock. If you branch, the other threads are stalled. It's possible on the newest architectures that some incantation of barrier is functionally identical to bar.sync, but that isn't the question as I understood it

"Instruction barrier{.cta} has optional .aligned modifier. When specified, it indicates that all threads in CTA will execute the same barrier{.cta} instruction. [...] bar{.cta}.sync is equivalent to barrier{.cta}.sync.aligned."

@talonmies Looks like bar is a specialization of barrier, i.e. the previously cited properties should also apply to bar.

@paleonix: Again, no. The original bar.sync instruction, which is the subject of this question,  is the original __syncthreads() functionality at the PTX level.. It has been in CUDA since the beginning of CUDA, PTX 1.0 running on the original G80. All the barrier functionality is much, much, much newer.  In no way is it a “specialisation” of barrier. It predates it by about 10 years

@talonmies But it is "equivalent" according to the documentation and should therefore have the same properties. If you like it better in terms of history, we can call barrier a generalization of bar instead.

@talonmies Edited the question and restricted scope to A100 and H100 only. This should resolve your concern that bar.sync predates the new semantics. @paleonix seems to be correct that on recent architectures, bar is simply a special case of barrier, and the memory fence properties of barrier apply to bar.

With respect to L1/L2 cache in the general case, it would be arch-specific. For A100/H100 assuming L1 caching is not disabled, its reasonable to assume it would be consistent with the specified behavior (to wit: "A memory write (e.g., by st, red or atom) has been performed when the value written has become visible to other threads participating in the barrier,") that it would need to get into L1.  Keep in mind PTX is a virtual machine specification.

actual latencies are not published by NVIDIA. Any sensible answer could only be based on conjecture, or else careful benchmarking, which would imply a GPU arch dependency for interpretation of results applicability. It is certainly not "Once data hits DRAM?".


how long does it take until global stores are visible?

How long is a piece of string?
As you already write in your question, it depends on the cache your data lands in. Unless it is evicted, data will stay in the L1 cache and so on throughout the cache hierarchy.
bar.sync is a __syncthreads() and works on a block level, i.e. on a single multiprocessor.
If you are lucky the __syncthreads() can be very fast, it depends on the writes between successive syncs.
A somewhat recent paper for Ampere: Demystifying the Nvidia Ampere Architecture through Microbenchmarking details the time it takes to execute common instructions on Ampere. For Hopper, see: Benchmarking and Dissecting the Nvidia Hopper
GPU Architecture
They list:



Location
Ampere (paper1)
Ampere (paper2)
Hopper (paper2)




Global memory
290
466
479


L2 cache
200
262
263


L1 cache
33
38
41


Shared Memory (ld/st)
23/19
?/29
?/29



My own experience lines up more with paper1 than with paper2.
If you have access to such a machine, you can easily time it yourself using the following code:
__device__ uint64_t GetGlobalClock() { //volatile + memory to prevent reordering
    //return clock64();
    uint64_t start;
    //do not use clock32!!, this is very slow.
    asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(start) :: "memory");
    //asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(start));
    return start;/**/
}

__global__ void TimeSync(int* data, int musthave) { //parameter to trick the optimizer
    //do init
    __syncthreads(); //wait for stuff to stabilize
    for (auto r = 0; r < 5; r++) { //always run a loop, the first run always  takes > 500 cycles.
        const auto StartTime = GetGlobalClock();
        data[threadIdx.x] = musthave * r;    
        __syncthreads();
        const auto EndTime = GetGlobalClock();
        if (threadIdx.x < 32) {
            printf("data[%i] = %i, Time = %i cycles\n", threadIdx.x, data[threadIdx.x], int(EndTime - StartTime));
        }
    }
}

This will measure L1 latency.
You have to ensure eviction from L1 if you want to measure L2 latency, etc.
On my machine, an RTX 3070, I get:
...
data[25] = 20, Time = 43 cycles
data[26] = 20, Time = 43 cycles
data[27] = 20, Time = 43 cycles
...

So 33 cycles for the L1 write plus 8 cycles for the __syncthreads() plus 2 cycles for the clock64().
If you want your threads to line up, but don't want to incur waits due to memory latency, you can perhaps use a spin-wait loop?
__shared__ uint32_t arrive_barrier;
atomicAnd(&arrive_barrier, 0);
constexpr auto blockwarps = 32; 
constexpr auto arrive_mask = -1u >> (32 - blockwarps);
//do work
const auto warpid = threadIdx.x / 32;
while (atomicOr(&arrive_barrier, 1u << warpid) != arrive_mask) {
    __nanosleep(1);
}

Obviously, this will only ensure memory safety with regards to shared mem.

Thank you for the detailed answer! One thing I am still curious about: does data have to hit L1 to become "visible" within a thread block? For example, on Intel Skylake CPUs, store instructions retire once data hits the store buffer. For the GPU case, if there is a single store buffer for the entire SM, then data wouldn't need to hit L1 to become visible within a thread block.

The honest answer is I don't know, but the latency suggests that it does need to hit the L1 cache before it can be seen by other threads. The GPU cores are much less sophisticated than CPU cores. Also, you are comparing stores in a single core (Skylake) vs stores on distinct cores (GPU).  The idea is to have very many simple cores and accept longer latency if that allows for increased parallelism (aka throughput).
